# CRM 2016 Deactivate plugin does not fire when records merged

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a plugin that fired when the record is deactivated.

Below is the code -

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("EntityMoniker") && context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"] is EntityReference)
            {
                EntityReference EntityRef = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["EntityMoniker"];

//code continues
```

}

And i have registered the plugin on SetState and SetStateDynamicEntity steps.

The plugin fires when the record is directly activated or deactivated. However when the 2 records are merged, the other record gets deactivated, at this point, the deactivation plugin does not work.

After the suggestion received from the same blog -

i registered the same plugin with some modifications in the code at "Merge" event.

Below is the code -

```
 if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference)
            {

                EntityReference EntityRef = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];


                if (EntityRef.LogicalName != "account")
                    return;


                SubOrdinateRecord = (Guid)context.InputParameters["SubordinateId"];
```

However after i get the subordinate record i need to get its related record and deactivate it

However i am unable to get the related record.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your observations are correct. A MergeRequest does not trigger a SetStateRequest, so you will have to register a plugin on both messages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However when registered on Merge it will fire on both records. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: What do you mean with "it will fire on both records"? Only 1 MergeRequest will fire. You can then look at [MergeRequest.SubordinateId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.mergerequest.aspx) to get the guid of the record that will be deactivated during the merge.

Comment: Ok so you mean i need to register the plugin on Merge event and then in the plugin code find the subordinateid ?

Comment: I tried it and yes i am able to get the other record, However, what i actually need to do is, find its related record and deactivate it, but it does not seem to find its related record, like if i have account 1 and account 2, so on deactivate, it finds the related record of account 2 and deactivates it. But here it is unable to get account 2 related record.Please suggest

Comment: I do not follow. What do you mean when you say "related record"?

Comment: i am not able to get Subordinateid, i registered the plugin on all the events, prevalidation, preoperation and post. I used to the event Merge

Comment: i am just a step away, kindly suggest i have updated my question